# IOTA Identity error while issuing unsigned verifiable credential

Tags: javascript

My code is running all good except when trying to issue an unsigned credential. I have already tried to figure out what's going wrong but I can't figure it out.
My import of the static testIssuer and the structure of the credential object is fine but the console log of the unsignedVc does not get displayed. That means that the code get's terminated while trying to create the unsigned credential with the `VerifiableCredential.extend()` function.
Here is the extract and the full file is below.
Extract:

```
    const personalInformation = {
      id: user.doc.id.toString(),
      name: {
        first: firstName,
        last: lastName
      },
      birthDate: birthDate,
      sex: sex,
      email: email,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      address: {
        street: streetNumber,
        city: city,
        state: state,
        postalCode: postalCode,
        country: country
      }
    }

    console.log(personalInformation)

    const unsignedVc = VerifiableCredential.extend({
      id: "http://example.edu/credentials/3732",
      type: "personalInformationCredential",
      issuer: testIssuer.doc.id.toString(),
      personalInformation,
    })

    console.log("Unsigned verifiable credential", unsignedVc)
```

Full post request:

```
const express = require("express");
const Identity = require("@iota/identity-wasm/node")
const cors = require("cors");
const server = express();
const testIssuer = require("./testIssuer.json")

const {
  Digest,
  DID,
  Document,
  KeyCollection,
  KeyPair,
  KeyType,
  Method,
  VerifiableCredential,
  VerifiablePresentation,
} = Identity

const CLIENT_CONFIG = {
  network: "main",
  node: "https://nodes.thetangle.org:443",
}

server.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }))
server.use(express.json())

server.post("/create", async (req, res) => {
  const {firstName, lastName, birthDate, sex, email, phoneNumber, streetNumber, city, state, postalCode, country} = req.body;
  const name = `${firstName} ${lastName}` 

  try {
    const reqIsIncomplete = Object.values(req.body).find(value => !value);
    if (reqIsIncomplete) {
      return res
        .json({
          message: "You are missing personal information",
          success: false
        })
        .status(500);
    }

    // helper function
    function generateUser(name) {
      const {doc, key} = new Document(KeyType.Ed25519)
      
      return {
        doc,
        key,
        name,
      }
    }

    // Generate a KeyPair, DID, and Document for user
    const user = generateUser(name)
    // Sign users DID Documents
    user.doc.sign(user.key)
    
    user.message = await Identity.publish(user.doc.toJSON(), CLIENT_CONFIG)
    console.log(`Published user: https://explorer.iota.org/mainnet/transaction/${user.message}`)

    const personalInformation = {
      id: user.doc.id.toString(),
      name: {
        first: firstName,
        last: lastName
      },
      birthDate: birthDate,
      sex: sex,
      email: email,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      address: {
        street: streetNumber, //Schuldorffstraße 10
        city: city,
        state: state,
        postalCode: postalCode,
        country: country
      }
    }

    console.log(personalInformation)

    const unsignedVc = VerifiableCredential.extend({
      id: "http://example.edu/credentials/3732",
      type: "personalInformationCredential",
      issuer: testIssuer.doc.id.toString(),
      personalInformation,
    })

    console.log("Unsigned verifiable credential", unsignedVc)

    // Sign the credential with testIssuer's Merkle Key Collection method
    const signedVc = testIssuer.doc.signCredential(unsignedVc, {
      method: method.id.toString(),
      public: keys.public(0),
      secret: keys.secret(0),
      proof: keys.merkleProof(Digest.Sha256, 0),
    })

    console.log("Verifiable Credential", signedVc)

    if (!testIssuer.doc.verify(signedVc)) {
      return res
        .json({
          message: `Error creating credentials for you, ${firstName}`,
          success: false
        })
        .status(500);
    }

    return res
      .json({
        id: user.doc.id.tag,
        docHash: user.message,
        pubKey: user.key.public,
        privKey: user.key.secret,
        credential: signedVc,
        message: `You have successfully created your digital identity, ${firstName}`,
        success: true
      })
      .status(500);
  } catch (error) {
    return res
      .json({
        error: error,
        message: "There was a Problem with our Servers",
        success: false
      })
      .status(500);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an error using your code

> Missing property: `credentialSubject`

Instead of:

```
const unsignedVc = VerifiableCredential.extend({
  id: "http://example.edu/credentials/3732",
  type: "personalInformationCredential",
  issuer: testIssuer.doc.id.toString(),
  personalInformation,
})
```

Try:

```
const unsignedVc = VerifiableCredential.extend({
  id: "http://example.edu/credentials/3732",
  type: "personalInformationCredential",
  issuer: testIssuer.doc.id.toString(),
  credentialSubject: personalInformation,
})
```